# AWS [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I used SSH Secure Shell and run with linux command line and tried to stop and start the Instance. But I got an error. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Command as below:

```
[tomcat@dlap54v ~]$ aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-e3a2b929
```

Command Output:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ec2.ap-southeast-1a.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

Comment: Have you defined the `region` that you wish to connect? usually, it is defined as a environment variable OR as a `--region` parameter in the command itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of region. 
I used Asia Pacific (Singapore) for the region because I am from Singapore. It keeps show error like "Name or service not known"
So, what you can do is choose US East(N.Virgina).
It's working for me now.