# Not able to send email within lambda function using httpclientlibrary

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a code using http.client library in python that sends email to others.I tested this in jupyter notebook and am able to send an email.

But when I tried the same inside lambda AWS,I get an error.Below is my code:

```
import http.client
import mimetypes

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("mail.us-east-1.aws.cloud.xxx")
    payload = "{\n \"from\": \"xxx@zzz.com\",\n \"to\": \"xxx@zzz.com\",\n \"subject\": \"Test mail\",\n \"textbody\": \"Test body\",\n \"htmlbody\": \"<h3>Test body!</h3>\"\n}"
    headers = {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    conn.request("POST", "", payload, headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
    print("done")
```

Below is my error message:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno -2] Name or service not known",
  "errorType": "gaierror",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 15, in lambda_handler\n    conn.request(\"POST\", \"\", payload, headers)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py\", line 1230, in request\n    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py\", line 1276, in _send_request\n    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py\", line 1225, in endheaders\n    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py\", line 1004, in _send_output\n    self.send(msg)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py\", line 944, in send\n    self.connect()\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py\", line 1392, in connect\n

    super().connect()\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py\", line 915, in connect\n    self.sock = self._create_connection(\n
 "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/socket.py\", line 787, in create_connection\n    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/socket.py\", line 918, in getaddrinfo\n    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):\n"
  ]
}
```

Here the line number 15 points to :

```
data=res.read()
```

I am new to lambda and am not sure if I am missing out something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error refers to a failure in name resolution while looking up address of the endpoint you're trying to reach.

It might happen if you try to connect to AWS resource in other region. Take a look at previous question: [AWS [Errno -2] Name or service not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009762/aws-errno-2-name-or-service-not-known)